# How to sample a 3-vector with given 2-margins?

Tags: st.statistics

Let $X$ is a discrete random vector of length three whose coordinates take integer values. We suppose approximate knowledge of all three 2-margins for $X$ and wish to create samples (say 10,000 examples) accordingly. Specifically we suppose that $I$, $J$ and $K$ are the dimensions of the lattice and for $i \in \{1,..,I\}$, $j \in \{1,..,J\}$ and  $k \in \{1,..,K\}$ we desire:

$a_{j,k} \sim \frac{1}{I} \sum_{i=1}^I x_{i,j,k}$, $b_{i,k} \sim \frac{1}{J} \sum_{j=1}^J x_{i,j,k}$ and $c_{j,k} \sim \frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^K x_{i,j,k}$

where $x_{i,j,k}$ denotes the number of occurrences of the value $(i,j,k)$ in our sample and $a$, $b$ and $c$ are known tables. Leaving ajar the precise joint distribution desired and the tolerance allowed in 2-margins, is there a fast way to sample $X$?

ps: I am a new user so could not add these tags:
polytopes, contingency-tables, copulas, markov-bases,maximum-entropy

Comment: In the case of two dimensional contingency table, one could do a Gibbs sampler on a $2 \times 2$ block maintaining the row and column sum within that block only. Presumably that's still the case with 3-dimensional table with 2-dimensional marginal. The convergence rate however is far from clear. I heard that in the 2-dimensional case the best mixing time upper bound is $O(n^5)$.

Comment: Thanks John and yes, I share similar sentiments about the speed.  